# How to display image from an RSS Feed description using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rss

Im working in PHP Laravel to build an RSS FEED READER

I have read the XML file and it displays the title, description and link.
But the description contains image which i don't know how to display as an image.
Now the image part comes in html format as shown below:

[image]

Instead i want it to be displayed like this:

[image]

Here is my html code where the rss feed content display happens:

```
 @foreach ($feed->item as $item)
        <tbody>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <a href="{{ $item->link }}">{{ $item->title}}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-header">
              <a href="{{ $item->link }}">{{ $item->thumbnail}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              {{$item->description}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
```

Can somebody please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have HTML in your `$item->description` using the double Mustache`{{ }}` You are telling Laravel escape the data.

To render the HTML, you need to use instead `{!! !!}`

```
    <div class="card-body">
      {!! $item->description !!}
    </div>
```

You can see more in the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data